# how to hide my twilio number from receiver when sending response

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am developing an app in android which send messages to users. I am using php for my api. when user send a message from the app, php sends back a response based on what they send.

Is there a way I can hide the twilio number from been known to the users or convert the number to a string when sending back response to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

If preventing the user from seeing the actual phone number, you could look at Twilio's Proxy service (in Beta). https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api

Another option would be to register a short code with the phone number.  https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-short-code

Comment: I would like them to see a name instead of number.